# jquery set a minimum value

Tags: jquery, attributes, default

I'm using jquery to find the value of an attribute

```
var dataWidth = jQuery('#myContainer').attr('data-width');
```

I'm trying to check the dataWidth var is both a numeric value and is less than 320. If it's not then set a default value. Here is what I have at the moment.

```
if(parseInt(dataWidth) > 320) {
        var dataWidth = 320
}
```

Can anybody let me know what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parseInt()` will return `NaN` if the string passed in cannot be converted to a number properly. **Any** equality/inequality comparison between `NaN` and any other number (or even `NaN` itself) will return false. (`NaN < 320` and `NaN > 320` return false.)

That's why you should also use `isNaN` to check if `dataWidth` is `NaN`:

```
var dataWidth = parseInt(jQuery('#myContainer').attr('data-width'));

if (isNaN(dataWidth) || dataWidth > 320) {
  dataWidth = 320;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( parseInt( $('#myContainer').data('width') ) > 320 ) {
    $('#myContainer').data('width', '320');
}
```